# Jersey Message Filtering based on Author Name should return more than one value

Tags: java, jersey

```
public Message getMessageByAuthor(String authorName) { 
    List<Message> nameList = new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
    Message message = null;
    if (!authorName.isBlank()) {
        Iterator<Message> iterator = nameList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            message = iterator.next();
            if (message.getMessageAuthor().contains(authorName)) {
                return message;
            }
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: @GET
@Path("/name")
public List<Message> getMessageByAuthor(@QueryParam("authorName") String name) {
  return service.getMessageByAuthor(name);
}

Comment: The return message must return more then one value

Comment: I'm not even sure where to begin in terms of editing your post to make it readable. I suggest you take some time to format it correctly. Read [ask]

Comment: The [edit history on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59492566/revisions) says different.

Comment: You're returning a single message when authorName is found. You should create a list, fill that list inside thw while and return it when done.

Comment: Also  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a  link to help any newbies on stack overflow to ask questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Triby mentioned in the comment, you should create a new List and add the elements that match your criteria and then return the list so that you get more than one element if they match.

```
public List<Message> getMessageByAuthor(String authorName) { 
    List<Message> nameList = new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
    List<Message> responseMessageList = new ArrayList<>();
    Message message = null;
    if (!authorName.isBlank()) {
        Iterator<Message> iterator = nameList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            message = iterator.next();
            if (message.getMessageAuthor().contains(authorName)) {
                 responseMessageList.add(message);
            }
        }
    }
    return responseMessageList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Santosh! This has resolved my query. Also will look into the link shared by you.